# How to update field of document where field is equal to in Firebase/Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to set up my Swift Firebase app to update a field of a users document when a function is called, so I can pass in the uid of the user, then find the document for that user and update a specific field for them within their document (isolationDate in this case).
When I do this I get an error.

```
func markPositive(uid: String){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments { (result, error) in
            if error == nil{
                for document in result!.documents{
                    document.setValue("1", forKey: "isolationDate")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it.

```
func markPositive(uid: String){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments { (result, error) in
            if error == nil{
                for document in result!.documents{
                    //document.setValue("1", forKey: "isolationDate")
                    db.collection("users").document(document.documentID).setData([ "isolationDate": "1" ], merge: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop the `document` variable is a [`DocumentSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot), which contains a snapshot of the data in that document. To update a document, you need to call `setValue` on a [`DocumentReference` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference). To get from a `DocumentSnapshot` to its `DocumentReference` you can read its [`reference` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#reference). So:

```
db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments { (result, error) in
    if error == nil{
        for document in result!.documents{
            document.reference.setValue("1", forKey: "isolationDate")
        }
    }
}
```